# Update column based on existence in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two SQL tables. I am trying to conditionally update the second based on detecting existence of a value, URL in the this example, in the first.

The first table, `Applications`, has the following data:

```
URL
-------------------------     
http://stackoverflow.com        
http://stackoverflow.com
```

In the second table, `Modernize`, I have the following data:

```
URL                            FieldToUpdate
--------------------------------------------
http://stackoverflow.com        
http://stackoverflow.com
```

The expected result would be if a URL is detected in the first table, `Application`, that in the `FieldToUpdate` it would set the text "Yes". Otherwise, it would set `FieldToUpdate` to No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `join`:

```
update t
    set fieldtoupdate = (case when f.url is null then 'N' else 'Y' end)
from secondtable t left join
     firsttable f
     on t.url = f.url
```